# What is the best approach to binding commands in a ViewModel to elements in the View?

Tags: wpf, design-patterns, mvvm, routed-commands

Anyone who has tried to implement RoutedCommands in WPF using M-V-VM has undoubtedly run into issues. Commands (non-UI commands that is) should be implemented in the ViewModel. For instance if I needed to save a CustomerViewModel then I would implement that as a command directly on my CustomerViewModel. However if I wanted to pop up a window to show the users addresses I would implement a ShowCustomerAddress command directly in the view since this a UI specific function.

How do I define the command bindings in the viewmodel, and use them in the view?

Comment: I arrived to the same solution... and I also wrote a blog entry about it :) You can find it [here](http://blog.notifychanged.com/2008/07/28/defining-commandbindings-in-the-viewmodel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [solution](http://codingcontext.wordpress.com/2008/12/10/commandbindings-in-mvvm/) that I came up with.